# Hot-Module-Replacement (HMR) suddenly stopped working in vue-cli 3 project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

in my vue project, created with vue-cli 3 i had hot reload working fine and than suddenly stopped.
in my console, when i save a `*.vue` file` i see:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] App hot update...
```

but that is it, it stops there, no reload in the browser.
i allready tried to reinstall my entire node modules, my webpack-dev-server,
tried adding

```
watchOptions: {
      poll: true
}
```

to my  `vue.config.js` file but nothing works. my configration file is very simple and straight forward:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    clientLogLevel: 'info'
  },
  pages: {
    app: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
            @import "@/assets/styles/variables.scss";
          `
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any idea what might cause that?

Comment: *for whoever coming back here, i never managed to figure it out, but the HMR suddenly start working again after a few days. couldn;t put my finger on the reaason